# How can you update the header of a message in a kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

is it possible to update the header of a message in a kafka topic? That is, when I attach a consumer to a kafka topic, can I somehow use this consumer to update the header of the message that I am consuming?

Comment: No, it's not possible to update the header of a message once it has been published to a Kafka topic. Headers are immutable. The only way you can do this is to create a new message with the updated headers and publish it to the Kafka topic.
Regarding the second part of your question: consumers are only responsible for reading messages from a topic and processing them.

Comment: @RAI why not post this as an answer? This is the correct reply, records in Kafka are immutable, you can't edit them.

Comment: Removed tags. Answer is the same for all kafka clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to update the header of a message once it has been published to a Kafka topic. Headers are immutable. The only way you can do this is to create a new message with the updated headers and publish it to the Kafka topic. Regarding the second part of your question: consumers are only responsible for reading messages from a topic and processing them.